# Getting System information using Reg Query

Tags: registry

How to get the following details using Reg Query Command?

1. Operating system details such as name,servicepack,version, and os architecture.
2. System details such as manufacturer name and model name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These may work.
for OS info:-

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

for hardware :-

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System
```